# How do I make voice assistant stop listening to me on command and start listening on command

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi so I made a python voice assistant and I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how to pretty much disable it without it exiting/ending script, so for example I say "go to sleep" it will stop listening to me or doing tasks for me but it wont exit and when I say "wake up" its back online and will listen to what I say and do my tasks

Here's the code I used:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import datetime
import pywhatkit
import webbrowser as wb
import os
from requests import get
import wolframalpha

#wolframalpha
try:
    app = wolframalpha.Client('')
except Exception:
    print("Some features are not working")

#pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[4].id) #changing index changes voices
engine.runAndWait()


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
        return ""
    return query


def wish():
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir!")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good after noon Sir!")
    elif hour >= 18 and hour < 24:
        speak("Good evening Sir!")
    
    speak("I am jarvis your personal assistant")


def time():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    speak(Time)


def date():
    year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
    date = int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
    speak(date)
    speak(month)
    speak(year)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    while True:

        query = takeCommand()

        if 'according to wikipedia' in query.lower():
            speak('Searching wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            try:
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=3)
                speak(results)
            except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
                pass

        elif 'numbers' in query.lower():
            try:
                res = app.query(query)
                speak(next(res.results).text)
            except:
                print("Internet connection error ")

        elif 'science' in query.lower():
            try:
                res = app.query(query)
                speak(next(res.results).text)
            except:
                print("Internet connection error ")
            

        elif 'what is your name' in query.lower():
            speak("My name is Jarvis, I am your personal assistant"
```

Comment: Careful about API key :)

Comment: yes but I changed it i accidentally put it in lol

Comment: There's an edit history (even if the question is "deleted"). You should get a new API key!

Comment: I already did as soon as he asked me what it is lol but thanks

Comment: Besides of that: how to you want to give a command if the assistant is not listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a boolean variable,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    is_taking_commands = True
    while True:
        query = takeCommand()
        if 'go to sleep' in query.lower():
            is_taking_commands = False
        if 'wake up' in query.lower():
            is_taking_commands = True
        if not is_taking_commands:
            continue
        if 'according to wikipedia' in query.lower():
            speak('Searching wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            try:
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=3)
                speak(results)
            except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
                pass

        elif 'numbers' in query.lower():
            try:
                res = app.query(query)
                speak(next(res.results).text)
            except:
                print("Internet connection error ")

        elif 'science' in query.lower():
            try:
                res = app.query(query)
                speak(next(res.results).text)
            except:
                print("Internet connection error ")
            

        elif 'what is your name' in query.lower():
            speak("My name is Jarvis, I am your personal assistant")
```

You also had missed a bracket at the end

Comment: actually I accidentally deleted the bracket but ill try what u sent me rn and tell u if it worked

Comment: @sabik Your correct, I will edit my answer

Comment: oh its incorrect alright ill wait for the edit thank you

Comment: @Chexz I have edited it now, let me if it works for you.

Comment: The `takeCommand()` function probably shouldn't say "Listening" when it's in the sleep mode, but that's minor fine-tuning